# Doctrine query SQL to DQL

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have a select with SQL which is working perfectly, but I cannot translate this query to DQL with `createQueryBuilder()`.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT distinct c.name_id
FROM cultures AS c
LEFT JOIN ilots AS i ON i.exploitation_id = 1
```

My current code:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->leftJoin(Ilots::class, 'i', 'ON', 'i.exploitation = 1')
        ->distinct()
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

And the error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 74: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'

Comment: is there any relationship between Cultures and Ilots ?

Comment: Yeah he have on Cultures ilot_id to id of ilot Entity

Answer (score 1):

In DQL `ON` doesn't exist, you have to use `WITH` instead.

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->leftJoin(Ilots::class, 'i', 'WITH', 'i.exploitation = 1')
        ->distinct()
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

[Documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.7/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.html#method_leftJoin)

Answer (score -1):

If there is relationship between the Entity:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->distinct()
        ->from('cultures', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.ilots', 'i')
        ->where('i.exploitation = 1')
        ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```